# Mongoose: Nested Schema Array is throwing an error that _id = null and _id cannot be duplicated

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, nested, database-schema

I am building an online ordering website where an orderSchema contains a nested array of itemSchema, however, Mongoose is throwing

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: restaurant.orders index: items._id_1 dup key: { items._id: null }
```

I've tried a few different things but nothing seems to work, I keep getting that `items._id` is `null` when I'm not even trying to declare an `_id` for `items`.

Here are my models.

```
const orderSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  customer_name: String,
  phone_number: String,
  _id: String,
  orderItems: [
    {
      _id: Number,
      itemPrice: Number,
      items: [{ type: itemSchema, _id: false }],
      quantity: Number,
      type: { type: String },
    },
  ],
  total: Number,
});

export const itemSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  price: Number,
  _id: String,
  cooking_time: String,
  options: [
    {
      name: String,
      price: Number,
      checked: Boolean,
    },
  ],
  flavors: [
    {
      isValid: Boolean,
      checked: Boolean,
      id: String,
      value: String,
    },
  ],
  sizes: [
    {
      isValid: Boolean,
      checked: Boolean,
      id: String,
      value: String,
      price: Number,
      inches: Number,
    },
  ],
});
```

the `itemSchema` needs to have an `_id` because my menu items are being held in a collection separate from my orders. However, `orderItems.items` does not need an `_id`, it's just an array.
Essentially I can put one document into my orders db but as soon as I try to create a second document it throws the error.
I can't wrap my head around why an array would need an `_id`, and why declaring `_id: false` doesn't work even though the individual item id's are unique.
Also, not sure if this is related or not, but I try to make my `_id`'s of type `String`but mongoose keeps converting them to `Double`'s.
Also, yes, I've looked at other posts about the same topic, but none of those have been helping. I've tried a lot of different things at this point.

Comment: You have a unique index on `items._id` so you cannot have two objects in the `items`  array both with `null` as the the `_id`. I suspect the index was created and then you modified your schema now you have this problem. Have a look on the index tab in compass. As an aside, there is no need to have `_id: false` because if items is it's own collection when you add an `item` to `order.items` array it's `_id` is the one used in the `items` collection.

Comment: Right on the money, I would double upvote you if I could, I had an old index from awhile ago that I had forgotten about. Thank you so much!!! If you make your comment an answer I'll mark it as so

Comment: Happy to help. See [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.dropIndex/) if you need to drop the index using mongosh. Good luck with your project.